# Elastic Search change index to a document

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I change the _index to an existing document in Elastic Search?

Example:

1) I create an index:

```
PUT /customer?pretty
```

2) I add a document:

```
POST /customer/_doc?pretty
{
  "name": "John Doe"
}
```

3) I create another index:

```
PUT /customer2?pretty
```

How Do I move the document created in step 2 into the new _index customer2?

Comment: This answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39274181/elasticsearch-how-to-make-a-1-to-1-copy-of-an-existing-index/39274485#39274485 (hint: use `_reindex`)

Answer (score 0):

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "customer",
    "type": "_doc",
    "query": {
      "term": {
        "_id": "fMn2OmcBEGEHUvm1g7Mi"
      }
    }
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "customer2"
  }
}

DELETE /customer2/_doc/fMn2OmcBEGEHUvm1g7Mi
```

where "fMn2OmcBEGEHUvm1g7Mi" is the id of the document.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to edit the [meta fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-fields.html) in a document. The best way would be to reindex it into a new index and delete the older index.

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "customer"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "customer2"
  }
}
```

Comment: this reindexes all the documents not just the selected one.

Comment: If you want to just index one document, then the below answer suffices.